# How do I call a Java static method with no arguments in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I am trying to figure out how to call a `static` method with no arguments in Clojure. Two (bad) examples are `(sun.misc.Unsafe/getUnsafe)` and `(Object/getClass)`, both of which throw a `CompilerException` caused by a `NoSuchFieldException`.

Yes I know there is a simpler way to call `getClass` and I should not be using `sun.misc.Unsafe` at all - just wondering how to call a no-arg static method in Clojure in general.

Comment: Object/getClass is not a static method. Call it on an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your examples don't seem to work, but the following does

```
(System/currentTimeMillis)
> 1398285925298
```

So that's the way to call a no-arg static method.

`Object/getClass` [doesn't appear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) to be a static method. It's meant to be called on an object, not a class.

Answer (score 3):

Getting at an `Unsafe` instance involves overcoming some access restrictions. The simplest way is to use reflection; see the [Java Magic. Part 4: sun.misc.Unsafe](http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/) blog post by Mykhailo Kozik for a description of this and other methods. Here's a Clojure snippet which does just that:

```
(let [f (.getDeclaredField sun.misc.Unsafe "theUnsafe")]
  (.setAccessible f true)
  (.get f nil))
;= #<Unsafe sun.misc.Unsafe@63124f52>
```

As pointed out by acomar and WolfeFan, `getClass` is not a static method -- it's an instance method declared by `Object` and therefore available on all objects:

```
(.getClass the-unsafe) ; the-unsafe obtained as above
;= sun.misc.Unsafe
```

As for the actual question, `(Foo/meth)` is the correct syntax for a no-argument static method call in Clojure.

Comment: I know about the access restrictions, but I was expecting a `SecurityException`, not a `NoSuchFieldException`.